# Why won't this VBA code write or update records to a new tab?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code:

```vb
Private Sub Query1_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim wsComments As Worksheet
    Dim wsQuery1 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim foundMatch As Boolean
    
    Set wsComments = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comments")
    Set wsQuery1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Query1")
    
    If Target.Row < 2 Or (Target.Column <> 31 Or Target.Column <> 32 Or Target.Column <> 33 Or Target.Column <> 34) Then Exit Sub
    
    'Check if there is a matching value in column A of "Comments"
    lastRow = wsComments.Cells(wsComments.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If wsComments.Cells(i, "A").Value = wsQuery1.Cells(Target.Row, "C").Value Then
            foundMatch = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox
    'If no match is found, create a new record in "Comments"
    If Not foundMatch Then
        lastRow = wsComments.Cells(wsComments.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wsComments.Cells(lastRow, "A").Value = wsQuery1.Cells(Target.Row, "C").Value
        wsComments.Cells(lastRow, "B").Value = wsQuery1.Cells(Target.Row, "AE").Value
        wsComments.Cells(lastRow, "C").Value = wsQuery1.Cells(Target.Row, "AF").Value
        wsComments.Cells(lastRow, "D").Value = wsQuery1.Cells(Target.Row, "AG").Value
        wsComments.Cells(lastRow, "E").Value = wsQuery1.Cells(Target.Row, "AH").Value
    
    'If a match is found, update the existing record in "Comments"
    Else
        wsComments.Cells(i, "B").Value = wsQuery1.Cells(Target.Row, "AE").Value
        wsComments.Cells(i, "C").Value = wsQuery1.Cells(Target.Row, "AF").Value
        wsComments.Cells(i, "D").Value = wsQuery1.Cells(Target.Row, "AG").Value
        wsComments.Cells(i, "E").Value = wsQuery1.Cells(Target.Row, "AH").Value
    End If
    
End Sub
```

I'm perplexed - what are some ways for me to troubleshoot? I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.

I am expecting that when I update column AE, AF, AG, or AH, it will first check to see if a record with the value of column C exists and if so, update the corresponding column, otherwise, it will write a new record.

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` not `Query1_Change`   Is your code in the worksheet code module?

Comment: @TimWilliams - yes, the code is in the Query1 sheet and I just tried updating to: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) with no luck.

Comment: At first glance i'd say all those "Or" are suspicious. I mean: whatever the column is, the macro will likely end at that line. For example: if the column is 33, it won't be 34, therefore the subroutine will be ended. If it's not 33 (therefore any number but 33), the subroutine will be ended. You probably need to get your boolean operators straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working for me:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsComments As Worksheet, id, rw As Range, m
    
    If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'only single-row updates...
    If Target.Row < 2 Then Exit Sub
    If Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("AE:AH")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set rw = Target.EntireRow
    
    Set wsComments = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comments")
    
    id = rw.Columns("C").Value
    m = Application.Match(id, wsComments.Columns("A"), 0) 'check for match
    'if no match then use next empty row in Col A
    If IsError(m) Then m = wsComments.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    With wsComments.Rows(m)
        .Columns("A") = id
        .Columns("B").Resize(1, 4).Value = rw.Range("AE1:AH1").Value 'AE1:AH1 is relative to `rw`
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim!! This worked like a charm...I'm sure you can tell I don't normally live in VBA. ;)

Comment: Worth noting this only triggers if one row is updated - if you (eg) paste into a couple of rows, or fill multiple rows at once it won't log the update.   Having said that - I'm not sure what purpose this serves?  It just copies data from one place to another, so it's not acting as any kind of tracking or log?